# How to install Fortran compiler on Ubuntu system without internet access?

Tags: ubuntu, compiler, fortran

I am working on a command-line Ubuntu system that is on a Parallella (a SOC with a RISC-based muti-core co-processor). I need a Fortran compiler to run some HPC benchmarks but my search is proving fruitless.

I've tried downloading iFort (the Intel suite was much too large for the system), installing gFortran (the GCC install proved a bit too complex), and installing other types of compilers. Alas, without internet access I can't seem to get any of my options working.

Any ideas on how to get a working Fortran compiler on my system? I'm guessing gFortran is the way to go, but I need internet access to download the prerequisites to build from source. Also for some reason, I seem to be missing a configure executable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If the compiler (a compiler) is in the repositories you could use the `--print-uris` option for `apt-get` and get a list of deb files to download, sneakernet them to your workspace, and install that way.  see https://askubuntu.com/questions/168352/how-do-i-generate-a-package-download-list